# Return generic class and type cast

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, collections

I am referencing a webservice project, it has 4 services, which uses its own model object.

> For example: **CalculationService** - *Response.cs* **DisplayService** -
>   *Response.cs*

```
public T ReturnResponse
{
  return genericResponse;
}
```

While consuming that

Inside CalculationService

```
var result= CalculationService.ReturnResponse(); //I want this to be namespace of 
CalculationService.Response class.

Inside DisplayService    
var result=DisplayService.ReturnResponse(); //I want this to be namespace of 
DisplayService.Response class.
```

A common method returning generic response class, that can be assigned (type cast) at run time.

Here is the code i tried:

```
public T ReturnMyResponse<T> where T:CalculationService.Response,DisplayService.Response,new()                                                 
{
var returnClass=new T();
if(typeof(CalculationService.Response)==typeof(T))
{ 
  var className=returnClass as CalculationService.Response;
  return (T)className;
}
if(typeof(DisplayService.Response)==typeof(T))
{ 
  var className=returnClass as DisplayService.Response;
  return (T)className;}return new T();
}
```

I see this error: The class type "DisplayService.Response" must come before any other constraints.

Comment: I don't see any actual generics here, and it's hard to follow exactly what you're doing here. If you could provide a [mcve] it would be a lot easier to help you than with abbreviated pseudo-code.

Comment: Please explain the question clearly. What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Sorry, i updated with my sample code, please let me know, if that helps.

Comment: So in your example you have two response classes and you want to create a generic method `ReturnMyResponse<T>` with constraint `T : CalculationService.Response, DisplayService.Response`, isn't it? It is impossible because `generic type constraints` set constraints for a single type `T`, and this type `T` must satisfy all constraints at the same time. In `C#` a single type `T` cannot inherit both these response classes. Why do you want to add such constraint to the method `ReturnMyResponse<T>`? I think that it is possible to create method `ReturnMyResponse<T>` without such constraint.

Comment: The method at the end is not correct, it's missing the parentheses. Please update it and provide full body so we can understand what you want to achieve. I understand you want to return two different types based on `T`, but where is the input?